# Cant pass parameter from one page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass parameter from one page to another. In my second page I cant access that parameter. i am new to asp. Please help me

[image]

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: And please show your work and exception message as a plain text, not as an image.

Comment: Please let us know URL format with parameters and one more thing that Request.QueryString["whatever"] always returns string so no need to convert it to string .

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `QueryString` seems not to contain the parameter `Parameter`, so it return `null` and `null` has no `ToString()` method.

Try:

```
var param = Request.QueryString["Parameter"];

if(param != null)
{
    string yourValue = param.ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps.

If you want to know, which url parameter are passed, you can take a look at `Request.QueryString`, becaus it contains all parameter. Be sure your are encoding them correctly in the URL:

```
www.example.com/home.aspx?param1=Hello&param2=world
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page url should be something like this for your code to work

`yoururl\mypage.aspx?Parameter=1`

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the parameter like that if you use post/get:

```
String name = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two pages PageWithParameter.aspx and PageRecievingParameter.aspx

Then you will be sending parameter from pageWithParameter.aspx in this manner

http://www.example.com/pageWithParameter.aspx?parameter1=value1

in the pageRecievingParameter.aspx code behind you will get the value of the parameter like this

```
String s = Request.QueryString["parameter1"];
```

For more information please refer into msdn

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx